# Nunit 2.5.10 - Not being able to compare two objects

Tags: c#-4.0, nunit-2.5

I've been looking for a way to check two objects, but I find Equals, Assert,AreEqual and some other ones and I do not know which one I should use. Furthermore, I've been making my tests with the new Nunit syntax and I have a hard time finding the new syntax for comparing two objects. Here's my test and my code:

```
[Test]
public void CheckForDriversSelectedMoreThanOnce_ReturnsDriversSelectedMoreThanOnceAndTheirSelectedPositions()
{
  //arrange
  Prediction prediction = new Prediction();

  Driver expected = new Driver { position = 1, name = "Michael Schumacher" };

  //act
  var actual = prediction.CheckForDriversSelectedMoreThanOnce();

  //assert
  //Assert.That(actual, Is.EqualTo(expected));
  //Assert.That(Is.Equals(actual, expected);
  Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
}

public Driver CheckForDriversSelectedMoreThanOnce()
{
  Driver driver = new Driver { position = 1, name = "Michael Schumacher" };
  return driver;
}
```

The line `Assert.That(actual, Is.EqualTo(expected));` and `Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);` gives me
  Expected: 
  But was:

The other line `Assert.That(Is.Equals(actual, expected);` gives me:
  Expected: True
  But was:  False

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to implement  IEquatable within your Class, similiar to;

```
   public bool Equals(Type other)
        {
            return Name == other.Name && Position == other.Position;
        }
```

I had this problem occur when attempting to compare 2 objects in a linq statement using 'Contains' and the above resolved that.

> The default implementation of instance
>   Equals() depends on your object type.
>   Reference types inherit
>   System.Object’s default
>   implementation, which is a simple
>   object identity (ReferenceEquals())
>   check. By default, reference types
>   will return true on instance Equals()
>   if and only if they are the same
>   object instance.

I am assuming that Assert.AreEqual(obj1, obj2) at some point does obj1.Equals(obj2), in which case they will not match.

Another option would be to Assert the actual properties, rather than matching the objects

```
Assert.AreEqual("Michael Schumacher", actual.Name);
```

Comment: Yes, and define the custom logic that dictates a 'match'